# How to stop audio player in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio-player

So in my app the user plays an instrumental when they hit the play button but when they stop it should stop the music. In my code when i add the code for the stop button nothing plays when i hit the play button but when i delete the code the play button works but the stop button doesn't.  I don't see why its doing that in my code.

Here is code:

```
@IBAction func playInstrumentalPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let saveFileName = nameSavedFile as String
    if (saveFileName != "") {
        let beatLocation = documentsPath + "/" + saveFileName + ".wav"
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: beatLocation)

        var error:NSError?

        player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: &error)

        if player.prepareToPlay() && player.play() {
            println("yes")
        } else {
            println("no")
        }

    } else {
        println("Not Available") //add alertview here
    }
}

@IBAction func stopInstrumentalButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if (player.playing) {
        player.stop()
    } else {
        println("Nothing is playing")
    }
      }
```

Comment: I wonder if you might have your iBAction outlets hooked up incorrectly... Maybe double check your xib/storyboard to see what methods the buttons are hooked up to.

Comment: thats what i thought i first so i deleted the code and button and made a new one and hooked it up and still doesnt change anything.

Comment: Could you please put some logging in `stopInstrumentalButton`, so that you can see if it gets called when you press play?

Comment: when i press play it gets called player.stop when i hit stop it prints Nothing is playing. I dont know why it does this when stop isnt pressed

Comment: Sorry, not sure exactly what you are saying. 1) Does `stopInstrumentalButton` get called when you press play? 2) Can you post a screenshot of the connections to `IBOutlets` that you have from your `xib`/`storeyboard`. Something else to try: put a break point in the `stopInstrumentalButton` method and press the start button. You will be able to see who is calling the method from the call stack.

Comment: lol so i looked at the connections in storyboard and saw that the play button was also connected to the stop button newbie mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just put my first comment into an answer so it is easy for people to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if you might have your `iBAction` outlets hooked up incorrectly... Maybe double check your `xib`/`storyboard` to see what methods the buttons are hooked up to